# Can't read the files which was uploaed in COdeigniter upload folder

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

Using codeigniter i've upload some files but i can't read those files.

```
    <?php 
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * file Info
     * @access priavte
     * @var object
     */
    private $uploadFileInfo;

    private $galary_path_url;

    /**
     * load the form and url helper library
     * load our new PHPExcel library
     * contuctor
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('excel');

        $this->galary_path_url = base_url() . 'upload/';
    }

    /**
     * load the upload form by defeault
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('/upload/upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    /**
     * does the upload 
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    function do_upload()
    {
        //set up the config file 
        //only doc,docx,xls,xlsx files can be uploaded
    $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = '|doc|docx|xls|xlsx';
    $config['max_size'] = '2000';

    //load the upload libraby with current config file
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    //if not uploaded
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
            echo  $_FILES['userfile']['type'] ;
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('/upload/upload_form', $error);
        } 
        //uploaded successfully. 
        else
    {
            $this->uploadFileInfo = $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('/upload/upload_success', $data);
            $this->pdfExport();
    }        
    }

    /**
     * detect the files and send to the right method
     * use the convert this to pdf file.
     * @access public
     * @return void Description
     */
    public  function pdfExport()
    {
        echo $filePath = $this->galary_path_url . $this->uploadFileInfo['upload_data']['file_name'];

            var_dump(file_exists($filePath));


    }

}
?>
```

bUT FILE_EXITS SHOWS FALSE. thanks in advance

Comment: 1st don't create Public Functions inside your controller because they are accessable for your users as URLs.. 
What did you get from echo $filePath ?

Comment: I wrote public function for testing purpose. I have to test it. then it'll be private. function. besides the problem has already solved. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the absolute filename, [you may want to use `full_path` instead of `file_name`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html). That will give you the absolute file system path to the file without building the path yourself. Currently, you're concatenating `base_url` with the file name which will not give you a file path, it will give you an `URL`.

Replace;

```
echo $filePath = $this->galary_path_url . 
                 $this->uploadFileInfo['upload_data']['file_name'];
var_dump(file_exists($filePath));
```

with;

```
$fullPath = $this->uploadFileInfo['upload_data']['full_path'];
echo $fullPath;
var_dump(file_exists($fullPath));
```

Comment: Thanks. can i use this path for loading this file to another class. like read the document?? Sorry if i ask a dumb question.

Comment: @nixon1333 Yes, as long as the class expects a filename, that should work just fine :)

Comment: actually i need the file from that loaction to read. Like I upload a xls file then read that file form that loaction to export it to pdf. Basically I need to read that file from that loaction.

Comment: thanks. then maybe it's a problem in LAMP. or permission problem.